# Need help accessing API data with jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm very new to jQuery. I'm just trying a simple example of pulling data into a webpage with the AJAX function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but in the console I get 'Unexpected token'. Just putting the URL in the browser I get the data, but I want to be able to parse it and use it as I'd like. Any help is appreciated.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        var url ='http://stats.ebash.com/api/v1/leaderboard';           
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {                         
                        summonerData = data.data.stats;
                        $('body').append(summonerdata)
                }
            })
    });         
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: apart from the syntax errors... it is a cross domain request so to enable ajax request to the said resource the service provider need to either support CORS or JSONP in the given case both seems to be not working... so one solution is to try to use your web server as an proxy by making the request to the server then from using the server send request to the said resource and return the value to the client

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error and miss a `}`.
Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var url ='http://stats.ebash.com/api/v1/leaderboard';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                summonerData = data.data.stats;
                $('body').append(summonerdata)
            }
        }
    })
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unjv8nhn/)**

Although in Demo you got and error but it's because JSFiddle and it's a different error from your problem.